# WebGL render to cubetexture error 1282 - "no texture bound to the unit 0"

Tags: c++, webgl, emscripten, webgl2

I'm trying to render a small scene into a cubemap to use for reflections in WebGL - using Emscripten (*C++ to JavaScript*). My code just goes through the 6 faces, and renders all objects into the currently bound side of the cube-texture. The code works on a desktop build, no errors. But WebGL says:

RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0.

Also I get error 1282, after checking with glGetError(); when I call "glDrawElements". Both messages appear 30 times (rendering 5 meshes into 6 faces - 6*5=30)

Fbo & texture creation

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_FboId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_FboId);

    glGenTextures(1, &m_glId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_glId);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, CUBEMAP_SIZE, CUBEMAP_SIZE, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

#if !WEB
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // Wrap_R is invalid in WebGL
#endif

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_DepthId);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_DepthId);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, CUBEMAP_SIZE, CUBEMAP_SIZE);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_DepthId);

    m_DrawBuffers[0] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
    glDrawBuffers(1, m_DrawBuffers);

    int fbo_Status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (fbo_Status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) printf(" ::ENGINE:: FBO Creation Failed! glError: %i\n", fbo_Status);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Rendering:

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_FboId);
    glViewport(0, 0, CUBEMAP_SIZE, CUBEMAP_SIZE);

    Object* objectPtr;

    shader.bind();
    shader.loadProjectionMtx(math::perspective(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.001f, 300.0f)[0][0]);
    shader.loadCameraPosition(m_Position.x, m_Position.y, m_Position.z);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    math::mat4 viewMtx(1.0f);

    for (unsigned int f = 0; f < 6; f++)
    {
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + f, m_glId, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (f == 2)
            viewMtx = math::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position - math::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f), math::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        else if (f == 1)
            viewMtx = math::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position - math::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f), math::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
        else if (f == 4)
            viewMtx = math::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position - math::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f), math::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
        else if (f == 3)
            viewMtx = math::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position - math::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f), math::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        else if (f == 0)
            viewMtx = math::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position - math::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f), math::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
        else if (f == 5)
            viewMtx = math::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position - math::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f), math::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));

        shader.loadViewMtx(viewMtx[0][0]);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Entities.size(); i++)
        {
            shader.loadModelMtx(m_Entities[i]->getMtx()[0][0]);

            objectPtr = static_cast<Object*>(m_Entities[i]);

            for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
            {
                glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + t);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, objectPtr->getTextureId(t));
                glUniform1i(objectPtr->getUniformLoc(t), t);
            }

            glBindVertexArray(objectPtr->getMesh()->getVao());
            int error = glGetError();
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, objectPtr->getMesh()->getNumberOfIndices(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
            error = glGetError(); if (error != 0) printf("GL ERROR: %i\n", error);
            glBindVertexArray(0);
        }
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

What did I do here that WebGL doesn't like? This is exactly how I render my scene when I just render it onto a 2D texture into another FBO. Only difference is that this time, I'm rendering into a cube texture.

Comment: Addition: Cube texture dimensions: 512 x 512.

Comment: When rendering where you call `glBindTexture` add some code to check the id is not 0. If it is that would be the error. Desktop GL supports the concept of a default texture, texture 0. WebGL does not.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response, do you mean the texture-id that OpeGL assigns to a GLuint variable upon texture creation (glGenTextures(1, &GLuint))? Thank you in advance

Comment: Right, just checked all the texture IDs, the fbo texture and the textures on the meshes. None of them is 0.

Comment: This is very confusing - when I use a different filtering for the cube texture it says that the texture bound to the unit 0 is no renderable. So it is bound apparently to the unit 0. But when I correct the filtering error, there's apparently no texture bound to the unit 0. What the... ?